# Way of saving arraylist of objects in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am having difficulty saving an ArrayList of objects to a file in android. I want to be able be able to read these objects and call a method on each object to get one of their attributes. Here is the object class

```
public class Transaction {

private double amount;
private String store;
private Date date;

public Transaction(){
    amount = 0.0;
    store = null;
    date = null;
}

public Transaction(double amt, String str, Date dat ) {
    amount = amt;
    store = str;
    date = dat;
}
```

}

In my activity I take input and create a new Transaction object. I then add the Transaction object to an ArrayList. I want to save the ArrayList to a file and be able to access the ArrayList from a different activity. In this different activity I want to access and call `getAmount()` on each object in the ArrayList to create a total amount and display it on screen. Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you can post your code. It would be better if the code is minimal, complete and verifiable (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) in your objects. There is [online tool](http://www.parcelabler.com/) that can helps. Ones you implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) you can pass the `ArrayList<Parcelable>` trough activities by putting the array in Intent's extras or save the array in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#java) for later usage.